# Remote user navigation of ui tabs using esp32 with node red

Tags: node-red

Is it possible to control the navigation of dashboard tabs
with an  input (mqtt input node) from a micro controller.

Sudo code for  basic idea :

Send  a string

Containing a command ie:

```
StringA=" go to topic/sensor_1"
StringB=" go to topic/sensor_2"

If button_A ==True {
  Mqtt.client.publish(StringA)
} else {
  Mqtt.Client.publish(StringB)
}
```

Once node red receives this command the tab that displays
Data from sensor_1 is activated. Navigation back to home or other pages ,made  by additional button press on micro controller .

Would you suggest  how this might be implemented in node-red,
Suggestions for any nodes / flows examples
That would be helpful as I develop  this application .

Why do I need to do this.
The physical display is mounted on a mast(sailing dinghy). I cannot physically reach  the display from my sailing position. However I've built a controller with the described button press that is conveniently in hand at all times

Answer (score 0):

From the information sidebar for the ui-control node which is part of the [node-red-dashboard](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-dashboard) package:

> **ui_ui_control**
>
> Allows dynamic control of the Dashboard.
>
> The default function is to change the currently displayed tab. msg.payload should either be an object of the form {"tab":"my_tab_name"}, or just be the tab name or numeric index (from 0) of the tab or link to be displayed.

Comment: Many thanks for your response,I think that's just what I wanted to know.im looking at the documentation for ui_ui_control ,figuring out how to implement  in my application, will search out  examples of that node many thanks  Ken

Comment: @Kenbrown https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers